# Associate facebook user check-ins to list of cities based on latitude and longitude

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, latitude-longitude, facebook-checkins

I am studying the development of an application that would show a user which cities in the world their friends have traveled to. To do this, I was thinking of getting a list of check-ins for each of the user's friends and mapping those check-ins to my list of cities based on each check-in latitude and longitude.
This looks like the only way to achieve this since the Facebook graph API doesn't return a city locationId that I could use to map the check-in city to my own city list.

I have absolutely no idea how to perform this mapping from a check-in lat/long to the lat/long I have stored for each city in my city table.
Could anyone point me in the right direction or toward a tutorial explaining how this can be done?

I only have a single pair of lat/long coordinates, so I suppose I would need to define for each city a range of latitudes and longitudes around the city center lat/long that would qualify a check-in for being deemed to take place in any given city, and then do a SQL query against my city table to find which city any given check-in finds itself in?
Or is there another / better way of doing this?
Thanks in advance for any tip and suggestion.

Lothaire

Answer (score 1):

You can use the search API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching to search for places around a specific lat/long location.

For example, caffes in San Francisco: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000

Similarly, you could search for places around your coordinates and look at places type to filter out cities. You would do that by calling https://graph.facebook.com/PLACE_ID and looking at the details. For example, in the search example above, Philz Coffee (first result) - https://graph.facebook.com/151116474914629 - gives you `"category": "Local business"`.

It's not ideal if you're aiming for cities, as check-ins are focused around places people go in the cities (you'd actually have more results of your friends checking into places probably, than them checking in to cities).

Comment: thanks for your answer but I think I would rather do the mapping of check-ins to cities locally rather than submitting another Open Graph API call for each check-in retrieved from the user's social graph for performance reason and to avoid sending too many requests to the Open Graph API.